# Annotation Text Size Doesn't Change on MATLAB Plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to add a textbox with no border to a MATLAB plot, but the font size doesn't seem to respond to changes I make to it.  E.g. even with size 50 font, this code

```
x=linspace(-pi,pi)
y=sin(x);
plot(x,y);

annotation('textbox',...
    [0.3,0.5,0.1,0.1],...
    'String','Hi',...
    'FontSize',50,...
    'EdgeColor','none')
```

produces this plot with default-sized text:
[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

Your code gives me this,

[image]

So I don't understand where the problem might be.

You might try changing the width and height of box like `'textbox',[0.3,0.5,1,1],...`.